# mysqldump doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried everything with the following code...in the commapnd prompt as well as php execution, but always generates empty 0kb file

```
$dmp = '"C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe"';

$command = $dmp. ' --opt -h '.$dbhost.' -u "'.$dbuser.'" -p "'.$dbpass.'" '.$dbname.' > "'. $backupFile. '"';
system($command);
```

Tried all sugestions in a previous post which was closed saying too localized or something like that. But cant understand why ??? As I still havent got the solution. Can somebody help ? I need to despearely back up my databases.

Comment: please post the exact error message

Comment: are you taking backup in windows server of linux server?? `"C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe"` means your trying to take backup in localhost??

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this command in my localhost host on windows, like

```
c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.20\bin>mysqldump --user=root --password=password test > d:\testing.sql

//--user=DBUserName
//--password=DBPassword
```

then your database name like i have given `test` and make sure about the correct sign `>` then the location with the database name from where you want to save your database. try this one hope this help you.